# iOS youtube iframe embed - won't go fullscreen

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

The video displays on the iPad. You can tap to bring up the controls. The fullscreen button is shown in the lower right, but tapping on it does nothing. It should send the player into fullscreen mode. Is there anything I can add to this code to make it work?

```
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body style=\"margin:0;padding:0;\" ><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"420\" height=\"226\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",video_ID];

UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:thumb.frame];
            videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            videoView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
            [videoView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
            [videoCcontainer addSubview:videoView];
```

Comment: take out the fixed width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Try using embed, and not an iframe: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
                      <body style=\"margin:0\">\
                      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                      width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                      </body></html>";
```